# Repopulate jQuery File Upload file list after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

### Background

I have a [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) widget that is part of a HTML form. The HTML form has a hidden input field that is populated with JSON by the jQuery File Upload widget upon a successful upload. This way, on the server side, I know which uploads to link to the rest of the form information.

When the form is submitted some server side validation takes place. Upon invalid input the page is reloaded and an error message is shown. All the form fields, including the hidden form field with the names and the paths of the uploaded files are still populated.

### Problem

My problem now is that after reloading the page, the table with uploaded files is empty. This makes the user believe that the uploads are gone, while in fact, the form still has a reference to the uploaded files in a hidden form field.

### Question

Is there a way I can get the jQuery File Upload widget to rebuild the file list upon page load so that users see the files they have uploaded before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanwhile, I've found the answer to my problem:

I had to manually trigger the done event.

```
if ($('#hidden-form-field-id').val() != "") {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'done')
        .call($('#fileupload'), $.Event('done'), {
            result: {
                files: JSON.parse($('#hidden-form-field-id').val())
            }
        });
}
```